# How to get literals from optional object param

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, literals, typescript-generics

I have following code:

```
const dd = ['a', 'b'] as const;
function cba<T extends readonly string[]>(a: { b: T }) {
  return (1 as any) as typeof a.b[number];
}

const a = cba({ b: dd });
const b = cba({ b: ['a', 's']});
```

Variable `a` returning `'a' | 'b'` type, variable `b` returning `string` type, which is what I wanted. Is there any way to make `b` property to be optional and then return above literals if exists and `string` if not? Here's what I was trying:

```
function cba<T extends readonly string[]>(a: { b?: T }) {
  return (1 as any) as typeof a.b extends 'undefined' ? string : typeof a.b[number];
}
```

but it returns ts error on `typeof a.b[number]` part with info that number cannot be applied to `T | undefined`. I was trying JS solutions also, to check if `b` property exists:

```
function cba<T extends readonly string[]>(a: { b?: T }) {
  const d = a.b;
  if (d) return (1 as any) as typeof d[number];
  else return (1 as any) as string;
}
```

but then it returning always `string | undefined` type. Any ideas?

PS. `(1 as any)` part is not important for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional types to do this:

```
type Values<T extends readonly string[] | undefined> =
    T extends readonly string[] ? T[number] : undefined;

const dd = ['a', 'b'] as const;
function cba<T extends readonly string[] | undefined>(a: { b?: T }) {
  return (1 as unknown) as Values<T>;
}

const a = cba({ b: dd }); // "a" | "b"
const b = cba({ b: ['a', 's']}); // string
const c = cba({}); // string | undefined
```